# need to install rails per new version or app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I installed ruby, rails, postgresql on freshly installed Manjaro linux.

```
[thiebo@Ruth ~]$ rails -v
Rails 6.0.3
[thiebo@Ruth ~]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]
```

I could create a new app with `rails new mynewapp` and that works fine.

I then downloaded my app already live on heroku. When I change directory to my app downloaded from heroku and command `rails server`, I get `bash: rails: command not found`.

the app from heroku was with rails 5.2.3 so I expected quite some error messages and necessary upgrade from rails 5.2.3 to rails 6.2. But I can't explain and don't know how to solve the command not found.

Comment: are you using any ruby version manager like rvm or rbenv?

Comment: Gems are usually installed per ruby version. Back in the day we used to use gemsets in RVM to isolate gem environments but Bundler has removed that need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Rails per each version of Ruby on your machine *and* you need to install each version of Rails that is required by apps running under a specific version of Ruby.

Therefore you need to run

```
bundle install
```

after downloading your application to install all required dependencies for the current Ruby version.

Comment: thanks ! But if I want to upgrade from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6.2, should I change that in the Gemfile before running bundle install?

Comment: Yes, in the Gemfile and the .ruby-version file depending on your setup.